# Audio format stored as ascii

Tags: audio

Are there any audio formats that are stored in a plain text file? For me it is easier to understand how they are stored and how they are read, rather than reading documentation on binary formats.

Comment: That would be incredibly inefficient. Besides, they'd still just be a long string of numbers. Not much different from binary data.

Comment: WAV files aren't all that complicated... once you get past the header, it is just a bunch of samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not. You can however easily, using for example a Python interpreter, print out any binary file as numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a hex editor! Much of the relevant information is written in the file header in a human-readable form. Especially with WAV, AIFF or SD2 files.

Answer (score 0):

adobe audition 1.5 can store audio file as ASCII text data format with an extension '.txt'  You can open it in notepad there will be minus and plus values of audio wave expressed in text. If you open it in aa 1.5 there will be audio.